# SQLAlchemy exception while concurrent queries

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I build multiple process for each cpu core. When I try to test it and send multiple requests from these processes, I get an exception:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

It works fine in single process mode, but when I build more than one process, this error shown.

Comment: can you add code snippets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection problems with SQLAlchemy and multiple processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279157/connection-problems-with-sqlalchemy-and-multiple-processes)

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks, it was useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can disable SSL on postgres config file. Change this line:

`ssl = true`

to

`ssl = false`

Config file is usually on `/etc/postgresql/*.*/main/postgresql.conf`

Answer (score 1):

It is likely because your processes are sharing the same connection pool and writing concurrently to the same postgres connection(s).

You do not provide much information on how you implement multi-processing, but if are forking processes, a common pitfall is that the engine is created before the fork, which initializes TCP connection(s) to the database which then gets copied over to the new processes and results in multiple processes interacting with the same physical sockets.

Remedies include:

- Disabling the pool and using an on demand connection: poolclass=NullPool,
- Re-creating the pool after fork: sqla_engine.dispose(), or
- Delaying the create_engine until after the fork